# Vue jest test: Cannot find module 'ui/table' from 'src/ui/test.vue'

Tags: ts-jest, webpack-module-federation

The project is divided into modules using the ModuleFederationPlugin. Cannot resolve import from neighboring modules when running tests.

I assume that the jest.config.js settings should be responsible for this. Nothing found on this subject

Comment: Text only question doesn't help to solve your problem, please provide code/configs and threw errors in your Q